# Subversion Case Statement - Two Argument - Unix Batch Script

Tags: bash, unix, svn

Two part question. I have a case statement like this for Subversion.

1. Is there a way to require [ -diff ] to have  two arguments ? but [ -help ] only to have one argument ?
2. What I want to do is the following

   sh Control.sh -diff "/MyFolder/Factory/Cow"

I want -diff to enforce a file location variable as [ $Location] .. that you would type in. I'm not sure how I would be able to save that so I can use

```
cp $Location $Subversion
```

in my script

```
case $1 in
        -diff)
                DIFF
                ;;
        -help)
                HELP
                  ;;  
            *)
                echo "none"
esac

DIFF()
{
cp $Location $Subversion
svn commit -m "file" $Subversion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you correctly, this should work:

```
case $1 in
        -diff)
                DIFF $2 $3
                shift 3
                ;;
        -help)
                HELP $2
                shift 2
                  ;;  
            *)
                echo "none"
esac

DIFF()
{
    Location=$1
    Subversion=$2
    cp $Location $Subversion
    svn commit -m "file" $Subversion
}
```